# CBC in hill cipher encryption

Tags: java, encryption

I am implementing Hill cipher depending on the explanation [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hill_cipher)

But I want to implement it using CBC mode, which says that each block must be `XORed` with the previous block, what about the first block, how it will be ?. 
B.S. each block is a 3-elemnents block

Comment: That why CBC mode requires an IV.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [CBC mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29), you need an additional initialization vector, to have something you can XOR the first block with. Simply generate n random bytes that will serve as your IV (where n is your block size). This IV need not to be kept secret and can be transmitted in public to the receiver who would then use it again to decrypt the message.